# SwiftUI: Filtering list based on categories in JSON file gives error "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression"

Tags: list, swiftui, filtering

I am trying to filter a list if the category of an element in a json file matches to, in this case, the given string "hoodies". Without the filter the list populates correctly so the error shouldn't be related to that part.

Code:

```
struct ProductList: View {
var filteredProducts: [Product] {
        products.filter { product in
            (product.category == "hoodies")
        }
    }

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
                List(filteredProducts) { product in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProductDetail(product: product)) {
                        ProductRow(product: product)
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC9z4.png)

I also provided my JSON file if needed, but i dont think its needed because the list populates perfectly fine without the filtered condition.
[JSON File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK2BF.png)

Thank you for your time!

** the text "hoodies" will be replaced by something else later on, this is just for testing **

Comment: Can you include the definition of `Product`, and minimal representations of `ProductDetail` and `ProductRow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not clear without the code for "Product" and "products",
how do you get "produtcs" into ProductList view? You could try this:

```
List(filteredProducts, id: \.self) {... }
```

or

```
List(filteredProducts, id: \.id) {... }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! 
Thanks for the feedback I will make sure to include everything next time! 